# Open foursquare app directly from NFC tag on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, foursquare, nfc

Has anyone been able to open the foursquare app directly from an NFC tag? If yes, what custom URL do you write onto the tag?

For android, a simple http://m.foursquare.com/venue/VENUE_ID does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same url format works for BlackBerry devices. The only thing that may be different is the formatting of the NFC tag itself. It needs to be an NDEF tag with a record type of "U". The Android app also will read tags of that format.

Comment: any idea about how to open the blackberry facebook app directly into a page?

fb:// works fine on android.

Comment: For BlackBerry 10 you can also use foursquare://venues/VENUE_ID